# jQuery serialize() does not work after ajax call

Tags: jquery

My ajax call works perfectly fine for first time. But subsequent calls don't serialize the form to fetch relevant data back to the page. There is only one form on this particular page and I may add couple of "non-serializable" forms later. Here is the code.

```
var getPage = function (event) {
    var ctx = event.data.ctx;
    var $a = $(this);
    var options = {
        url: $a.attr('data-action'),
        data: $('form[data-serializable]').serialize(),
        type: "get"
    };

    $.ajax(options).success(function (data) {
        $('#myResultsDiv').html(data);
        if (ctx == "...") {
            // some code
        }
    });
};

$('a[id="Next"]').on('click', { ctx: $('a[data-ctx]').attr('data-flag') }, getPage);
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: suggesting to serialize the form on click event and pass the serialize data to getPage function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Changed the code to `data: $('form[id="myFormId"]').serialize()`

Changed the jQuery selector to use **Form Id** instead of [data-serializable] attribute and it started working.

Comment: Why not just `$('#myFormId')`?

Comment: Yes, $('form#myFormId') will be better!